# Target each class and return a string and class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to add a span class of "pink" to the end of a string.

I can get this to work with one element, But when the page loads more than one, It keeps returning the very first element only.

I have created a [jSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Zj8FU/)

In that jsFiddle are two titles :

> 20 Smithsons Street
>
> 25 Jones Street

But it is only returning 20 Smithsons Street.

Is their any way I can target each element?

My jQuery is as follows :

```
// Style The Last Element In The Property h3 string

function change_colour()
{
    var property_title =  $('.property-title').html();

    var lastWord = property_title.substring(property_title.lastIndexOf(" ")+1);
    var lastIndex = property_title.lastIndexOf(" ")
    var property_title = property_title.substring(0, lastIndex);
    var style = '<span class="pink"> '+lastWord+'</span>';

    return property_title + style;
}

$(".property-title").each(function() {
    $('.property-title').html(change_colour());
});
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One less known thing is that you can pass a function to jQuery's [html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/#html-functionindex--oldhtml) method:

```
function change_colour(index, html)
    var lastWord = html.substring(html.lastIndexOf(" ")+1);
    var lastIndex = html.lastIndexOf(" ")
    html = html.substring(0, lastIndex);
    var style = '<span class="pink"> '+lastWord+'</span>';

    return html + style;
}

$(".property-title").html(change_colour); // reference to function!
```

Comment: You don't need the `.each()` either

Answer (score 2):

the problem is that you are not passing the correct reference to change_color() methos.

Try this solution.

```
    $(".property-title").each(function() {
            var property_title =  $(this).html();

    var lastWord = property_title.substring(property_title.lastIndexOf(" ")+1);
    var lastIndex = property_title.lastIndexOf(" ")
    var property_title = property_title.substring(0, lastIndex);
    var style = '<span class="pink"> '+lastWord+'</span>';
    $(this).html(property_title + style);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to reference the *current* property title:

```
var property_title =  $(this).html();
```

Comment: That's not enough by itself because `this` would refer to the global object.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is this line

```
var property_title =  $('.property-title').html();
```

which always fetches the HTML of the *first* matched element, as per the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/html/).

You should instead pass the element of interest as an argument (or `this`) since you already have this information inside the `.each` callback.

Using an argument:

```
$(".property-title").each(function() {
    $('.property-title').html(change_colour(this));
});

function change_colour(el)
{
    var property_title =  $(el).html();

    // the rest as before
}
```

Using `this`:

```
$(".property-title").each(function() {
    $('.property-title').html(change_colour.call(this));
});

function change_colour()
{
    var property_title =  $(this).html();

    // the rest as before
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Pass in the element and use that to capture the property title:

```
function change_colour(el) {
  var property_title =  $(el).html();
  var lastWord = property_title.substring(property_title.lastIndexOf(" ")+1);
  var lastIndex = property_title.lastIndexOf(" ")
  var property_title = property_title.substring(0, lastIndex);
  var style = '<span class="pink"> '+lastWord+'</span>';
  return property_title + style;
}

$(".property-title").each(function() {
  $(this).html(change_colour(this));
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dJUzx/7/)

Comment: Can be shortent to `$(".property-title").html(change_colour);` with `function change_colour(idx, oldhtml) { var property_title = oldhtml; // rest of code ... }` - [.html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/#html-functionindex--oldhtml)